# adding location field on biblatex entry

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to include in a bibliography with biblatex the location field in an inproceedings entry. A minimal working example is the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sorting=ynt,bibstyle=authoryear-comp,defernumbers=true,maxnames=300,firstinits=true,uniquename=init,backend=biber,dashed=false,arxiv=abs]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{pages}{\lowercase{pp.}#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{pages}{\lowercase{pp.}#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textbf{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{(#1)}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{#1}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
\usebibmacro{bibindex}%
\usebibmacro{begentry}%
\usebibmacro{author/editor}%
\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\nopunct
\usebibmacro{title}
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{byauthor}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{in:}%
\printfield{booktitle}%
\setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
\printfield{pages}
\newunit\newblock
\printfield{issn}%
\newunit\newblock
\printfield{location}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{pageref}%
\usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{trial,
location = {Venice, Italy},
author = {Doe, J and Mouse, M},  
booktitle = {Proceedings of my conference},
pages = {133--158},
title = {A possible title},
year = {2001}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to make the location entry to appear in the bibliography. Any clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `location` field is of the literal list data type. Since all formatting directives are specific to the data type, replace `\printfield{location}` with `\printlist{location}`.

A list of fields with their data type in the default data model can be found in the Database Guide of the biblatex manual.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
address  = {Venice, Italy}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is definitely not the problem in the code shown in the question. With `biblatex` the field `address` is a legacy alias for `location` and internally only `location` is used. The code example already uses `location` everywhere. But it is true that with most (if not all) BibTeX styles, you need to use `address` as `location` is not a supported field.