# biblatex \printfield prints nothing

Tags: biblatex

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{unpublished}{%
  \printtext{%
    \printfield{location}\addcomma\space%
    \printfield{year}\addcomma\space%
    \printfield{month}\addcomma\space%
    \printfield{day}}%
}

\addbibresource{my.bib}


\begin{document}

\fullcite{something}

\end{document}
```

and the respective bib file:

```
@unpublished{something,
  author       = {Me C. and You K.},
  title        = {Some Awesome Work},
  eventtitle   = {Workshop on Awesome Stuff},
  location     = {Some County in the U.S.},
  year         = {2018},
  month        = {9},
  day          = {7},
  howpublished = {http://www.someurl.com}
}
```

Compiling the above gives ", 2018, Sept.,".

Indeed the field `day` is not in the list of available fields given on page 12 of the [biblatex manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf). However, `location` is the list of optional fields, and is still not showing.

Are there any rules that govern this behavior, or is this a bug? Moreover, how can I display fields such as `day` above?

I am using the latest update of the 2017 mactex distribution.

Comment: `location` is a list, so you have to use `\printlist{location}`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122095/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/430833/35864

Comment: As for day, you should usually not have to write `\printfield{day}` or `\printfield{month}`. Instead you should use `\printdate` and customise the date format accordingly (if necessary).

Comment: In the MWE the outer `\printtext` is unnecessary (though it could be more useful if it applied additional formatting). You should also consider using the punctuation tracker and `\setunit{\addcomma\space}` instead of putting `\addcomma\space` directly. Have a look at §4.11.7 *Using the Punctuation Tracker* of the manual.

Comment: Actually the fact that you can not show `day` is not a problem of your code, it is a problem of your input. `day` is not a valid *input* field. `year` and `month` are supported for backwards compatibility reasons, but day-precision dates *must* be given in the `date` field in the form `YYYY-MM-DD`. Things should work when you say `date = {2018-09-07},` in the `bib` file.

Comment: @moewe I followed your advice on the date format, and also renewed the command `\newunitpunct`. All this works well, but I am having trouble with `\newblockpunct` and `\finentrypunct`, as `\newblock` and `\finentry` don't print anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I don't exactly know what you are trying to do with `\newblock` and `\finentry`. Can be more specific? (Though I must say that this is probably going to be a new question.)

Comment: @moewe I posted a new question, in case you want to take a look: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449923/biblatex-newblock-and-finentry-dont-insert-specified-punctuation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues at hand here.

As explained in [Unable to Call "Publisher" or "Location" in Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/430833/35864) and [adding location field on biblatex entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122095/35864) you actually need

```
\printlist{location}
```

instead of `\printfield{location}`. `biblatex`'s fields actually come in three flavours (i) field, (ii) list and (iii) name list and you have to use the right command (`\printfield`, `\printlist` and `\printnames` respectively) for each flavour.

The day issue is two-fold. `day` is not a valid *input* field. While `year` and `month` are retained for backwards compatibility, `day` is not. So if you want day-precision dates, you must use the `date` field in the `.bib` file

```
date = {2018-09-07},
```

instead of `year = {2018}, month = {9}, day = {7}` (which is wrong and will only come out with a `year`+`month` date, `day` is explicitly ignored).

But ideally you should also not use `\printfield{month}` or `\printfield{day}` (I would also argue that one should avoid `\printfield{year}` as well, but there may be legitimate uses for that), instead you should try to use `\printdate` which will print the date in the correct date format for the active localisation.

When you write your own bibliography drivers you should also look into using `biblatex`'s punctuation tracker. §4.11.7 *Using the Punctuation Tracker* of [the `biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) would be the obvious place to start. Normally you will want to wrap commands like `\addcomma\space` into a `\setunit` when they are used in a driver.

In the MWE the outer `\printtext` does nothing useful, so I would remove it, but that can be different in your actual document.